# another question about singularity and converge uniformly.

Tags: complex-analysis

a)Prove if $n\in \mathbb{Z}$ then,

$\frac{1}{\sin^2{z}}-\frac{1}{(z-\pi n)^2}$

has a removable singularity at $z=\pi n$ when $n=0$. Actually this is true for all $n$.

b) Prove that

$\sum_{n=-\infty}^{\infty} \frac{1}{(z-\pi n)^2}$

converge uniformly on every bounded set after dropping finitely many terms

c) use Liouville's theorem to prove that 
$\frac{1}{\sin^2{z}}=\sum_{n=-\infty}^{\infty} \frac{1}{(z-\pi n)^2}$

What my approch for a) is that use l'hopital's rule to prove the reciprocal of $\frac{1}{\sin^2{z}}-\frac{1}{(z-\pi n)^2}$ when $z$ approching $0$ is $3$. Which is neither $0$ or infinity. This means that the isolated singularity at 0 is neither a pole or essential.

b)

**Edit 1**

$A$ is bounded. So there are only finitely many $n$ such that $\pi n\in A$.
After removing these $ \frac{1}{(z-\pi n)^2}$, we get

Each $ \frac{1}{(z-\pi n)^2}$ is analytic and by maximal principle, they attain a maximum say, $M_n$ at $z_n$. Then $M_n=|{\frac{1}{(z_n-\pi n)^2}}|$. We have $|z_n|$ is bounded, so by integral test, resulting integral is $\frac{1}{\pi |z_n|}$ which is bounded.  So $\sum_{n=-\infty}^{\infty} M_n<\infty$.Hence by Weistrass m-test, the result follows.

c) By (a), we have $\frac{1}{\sin^2{z}}-\sum_{n=-M}^N\frac{1}{(z-\pi n)^2}$ has a removable singularity. So $\frac{1}{\sin^2{z}}-\sum_{n=-\infty}^{\infty} \frac{1}{(z-\pi n)^2}$ is analytic because, after remove finitely many terms,we have $\sum_{n=-\infty}^{\infty} \frac{1}{(z-\pi n)^2}$ is entire and bounded. By Liouville's theorem, we get $\sum_{n=-\infty}^{\infty} \frac{1}{(z-\pi n)^2}$ is a constant, but after submit numbers (e.g. $z=\pi/2$) we get the constant is actually $0$.

Comment: For b, try the Weierstrass M test.